# Borrow-checker behavior in if - else blocks

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Thanks to [@jmb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5397009/jmb) for pointing out that this is a known compiler limitation that has to do with lexical lifetimes. There is likely no easy way to solve the issue currently.

I ended up working around it by refactoring my code not to use the returned reference from `self._read_to_buffer()`, but to access the internal buffer directly.

```rust
if &self.buffer != "err" {
    Ok(&self.buffer)
} else {
    // The next line contains the explanation of the error, so read it
    let e = self._read_to_buffer();
    Err(format!("Unable to read line because of error: {e}"))
}
```

This was not a particularly nice solution for my actual problem as it involved exposing private variables through multiple layers of abstraction. A better solution may be possible though e.g. [https://crates.io/crates/polonius-the-crab], but I have not yet been able to get one to work. I am also not sure that I'm comfortable with bringing that crate into production.

---

Consider an input that contains either valid lines, or the message "err" followed by and explanation of the error, e.g:

```
"foo
err
explanation
bar
baz"
```

You want to return the line if it was valid, or an error with the included explanation otherwise.

```rust
use std::io::{BufRead, Cursor};

fn main() {
    let mut s = ValidLineReader {
        input: Cursor::new("foo\nerr\nexplanation\nbar\nbaz"),
        buffer: String::new(),
    };

    dbg!(s.next_line());
    dbg!(s.next_line());
    dbg!(s.next_line());
    dbg!(s.next_line());
}

struct ValidLineReader {
    input: Cursor<&'static str>,
    buffer: String,
}

impl ValidLineReader {
    pub fn next_line(&mut self) -> Result<&str, String> {
        let next = self._read_to_buffer();
        if next != "err" {
            Ok(next)
        } else {
            // The next line contains the explanation of the error, so read it
            let e = self._read_to_buffer();
            Err(format!("Unable to read line because of error: {e}"))
        }
    }

    fn _read_to_buffer(&mut self) -> &str {
        self.input.read_line(&mut self.buffer).unwrap();
        &self.buffer
    }
}
```

This will fail with the following error message:

```
  --> src/main.rs:27:21
   |
21 |     pub fn next_line(&mut self) -> Result<&str, String> {
   |                      - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
22 |         let next = self._read_to_buffer();
   |                    ---------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
23 |         if next != "err" {
24 |             Ok(next)
   |             -------- returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
...
27 |             let e = self._read_to_buffer();
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I understand that doing something like

```rust
let e = self._read_to_buffer();
println!("Unable to read line because of error: {e}");
Ok(next)
```

would be a reference error, since a call to `self._read_to_buffer()` mutates the buffer that `next` is pointing to. But we do not use `next` in the else branch, so why does the compiler seem to think that it is still borrowed?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why does returning early not finish outstanding borrows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51350561/5397009)

Comment: TLDR: this is a known limitation of the current borrow-checker implementation, that should be fixed by the experimental [Polonius](https://rust-lang.github.io/polonius/) borrow-checker available on nightly with the `-Zpolonius` flag

Comment: @Jmb You're probably right, it's a consequence of lexical lifetimes. I still need to find a workaround though, I don't suppose you have any ideas?

Comment: You can try with the [`polonius_the_crab` crate](https://crates.io/crates/polonius-the-crab).